# How do I copy error messages in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I just started with C# and VS, how is possible to copy my error message.

In the below image I want to copy 'System.Net.HttpWebRequest...

[image]

Comment: This question shouldn't be marked as "Off-Topic" since it's not off-topic.
This question is related to software tools commonly used by programmers (http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Not sure [OFFTOPIC] ?It is a valid question which the user dont have answer & related to a particular software tool usage. - IN error list window select only columns(Description normally) that you wanted to copy first and then copy, paste in google for solutions !

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Select "View" in menu bar and enable "Error List" which will pop up on the bottom of the screen by default containing all the errors with possibility to copy the message.

Comment: Even though this is the right answer, it's a real pain to use. What if you have many errors in the list? You have to scroll through the list and manually find the right one instead of hovering over the error in the file and copying it. There needs to be a better way.

Comment: Can you copy all of them at once? EDIT: CTRL-A to select all and then copy, works!

Answer (score 7):

You can use this extension:

#### [Error Helper](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MattLaceyLtd.ErrorHelper)

> Make it easier to work with items in the Visual Studio Error List by
> copying or searching (with Bing, Google, or StackOverflow) for just
> the description of an error.

[image: Error Helper usage]

> No more wasting time copying the whole row and then extracting the
> description. This extension adds helper commands to make it easier for
> dealing with errors.
>
> When there are bugs to fix, you don't want to be messing about with
> re-typing error messages or a clipboard full of unhelpful junk.
>
> Go to Tools > Options > Error Helper and choose to search with Bing,
> Google, or StackOverflow. You can also opt to remove file paths from
> search strings.

It's available for [Visual Studio 2022](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MattLaceyLtd.ErrorHelper) and [Visual Studio 2019](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MattLaceyLtd.ErrorHelper2019)

Answer (score 3):

Try to rebuild solution and then you can copy this error from Error List.

Comment: @Exception: No, it's an answer. That's how you copy the error message - you get it into the error list...

Answer (score 1):

Try to build your program, then from the Error List Window you can copy an error by pressing Ctrl+C (or right-clic -> copy)