# How do I copy error messages in Jupyter notebooks in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I have similar problem as described in [How do I copy error messages in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25442591/how-do-i-copy-error-messages-in-visual-studio)

[error message which I can't copy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDFnT.png)

However the proposed solutions (
#1.Select "View" in menu bar and enable "Error List"
#2. Use extension You can use this extension "Error Helper") are not working (#1. I don't have "Error List" to enable #2 VSIX extension is not working) are not solving the problem

Comment: 1) what version of VS Code do you have installed? I have 1.78 and I can select and copy that text. 2) Can you select that text?